# ¿Cómo se puede recuperar las publicaciones de un usuario con la API de StackOverflow?

Tags: api

Quisiera saber cómo se puede recuperar las publicaciones de un usuario con la *API* de *StackOverflow*.

Answer (score 0):

Me temo que con la API actual de stackoverflow no es posible, sin embargo si puedes recuperar los usuarios que hicieron una lista de preguntas que cumplan x filtro [aquí adjunto la documentación oficial sobre los usuarios](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-types)